Instead change the require of file:///home/ishan/.../node_modules/chai/index.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules
I'm currently running the latest version of Hardhat on WSL. I installed the npm packages for hardhat toolbox as per the demonstration given by hardhat.
However, it shows some error which I don't understand.
Initially, i was using 'const' and 'require' format. Then I changed to the 'import' format
Usually, imports() are used in '.mjs' modules. So i thought maybe I had to change the 'type' to 'module'. But that also did not work, as you can see in the third iteration.

Another interesting part is that the 'node_modules/chai/index.mjs' is already using an import statement!
Please guide me on what to do ahead.
Following is my script file.
// const {ethers} = require("hardhat")
// const {expect} = require("chai")
import {expect} from 'chai'
import {ethers } from 'hardhat'





describe("SafeHeiro Base Implementation", function(){
    it("Should correctly assign the value '3' to 'Test' key", async function () {
        const safeHeiro = await ethers.deployContract('safeHeiro')
        await safeHeiro.waitForDeployment() 
        await safeHeiro.callThis()

        expect(await safeHeiro.getValueOfThis()).to.equal(3)
    })
})


I deleted this directory of hardhat. Downloaded the sample javascript project after the 'npx hardhat init' command. Worked prefectly. Then I redid the work, the added the changes. And it worked well. I am unsure why. It may have to do with the order in which I performed these actions.

Steps: ->


npm install --save-dev hardhat


npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox


npx hardhat init (then selected 'empty hardhat.config.js' option)


Added the 'require' statement =>
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox')
at top of the hardat.config.js file.


One thing I did not do is run the 'npm init' command. I am unsure if that was the reason it worked out.

Please add information to the question using [edit] instead of comments. If you solved the issue and no longer need an answer, then either answer the question if you feel your answer is useful to others or delete the question

I no longer have the same code with me, but I found myself in a similar situation when I was trying to import {express} from 'express' package.
When importing cjs files, you don't need to use '{' and '}'. Directly name them as follows
import express from 'express'
import fs from 'fs'

Refer this one.
Unsure if anyone else would face a similar thing, but I again had a problem with libraries and feel it would be relevant to answer it here.
Here is the link from where I got the inspiration and solved my problem (again, with some other codebase, but similar/same problem)
Mix CommonJS and ES6 modules in same project
Check the answer by @rukonmin
